# How to run @Async method inside the @Scheduled one

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, asynchronous, scheduled-tasks

I have read many questions and answers about using `@Scheduled` with `@Async` in Spring but no one resolves my problem and my asynchronous method still runs single-threaded. So here is my Configuration class:

```
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SchedulerConfiguration {

    private final ThreadPoolProperties threadPoolProperties;

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor commonTaskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(threadPoolProperties.getCorePoolSize()); // 10
        taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(threadPoolProperties.getMaxPoolSize()); // 20
        taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(threadPoolProperties.getQueueCapacity()); // 5
        taskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("TEST");
        taskExecutor.initialize();
        return taskExecutor;
    }
}
```

Then we have a bean with the `@Scheduled` method:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ScheduledTask {

    private final ConfirmReservationTask confirmReservationTask;

    @Scheduled(cron = "${booking.scheduler.confirmReservationsCron}")
    public void process() {
        confirmReservationTask.confirmReservations();
    }
}
```

And finally, another bean (to avoid self-injection and proxy problems with asynchronous processing) with `@Async` method:

```
@Log4j2
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ConfirmReservationTask {

    private final ReservationService reservationService;

    @Async("commonTaskExecutor")
    public void confirmReservations() {
    ...
    }
}
```

unfortunately, this solution works in only one thread, however, the method uses the correct `ThreadExecutor`. How to solve it?

Comment: Hi, how do you define that this solution work on one thread? By default, @Scheduled work on one thread, but you then pass execution to `commonTaskExecutor`.
Try to view all current active threads via `jconsole`.

Comment: @shadownindzya I make thousands of operations in my async method's loop, and log the current thread name in each iteration.

Comment: I reproduced your configuration, and all work as expected
```
 16:27:15.001  INFO 5927 --- [pool-1-thread-1] stckovflw.example.ScheduledTask          : Started schedule at thread = pool-1-thread-1
16:27:15.004  INFO 5927 --- [pool-1-thread-1] stckovflw.example.ScheduledTask          : Ended schedule at thread = pool-1-thread-1
16:27:15.008  INFO 5927 --- [          TEST1] s.example.ConfirmReservationTask         : Run confirmReservations on TEST1
16:27:25.008  INFO 5927 --- [          TEST1] s.example.ConfirmReservationTask         : Run confirmReservations executed on TEST1

```

Comment: and with jconsole I see - `pool-1-thread-1` thread of Scheduled executor. And `TEST1, TEST2,...` threads of common executor pool.

Comment: @shadownindzya try to log the current thread name in a loop for eg 10000 times and you will always get TEST1 thread, at least for me it works like that

Comment: hm, do you mean inside that async method use infinite loop?

Comment: in this case, of course it will work on one thread. You should try call from infinite loop inside `ScheduledTask#process` method

Comment: @Scheduled(cron = "15 * * * * ?")
    public void process() {
        logger.info("Started schedule at thread = {}", Thread.currentThread().getName());
        for (int i=0; i<10000;i++) {
            confirmReservationTask.confirmReservations();
        }
        logger.info("Ended schedule at thread = {}", Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

Comment: Not infinite, just force the @Async method to run longer so it can uses different threads. My method runs for 1,5min and still on 1 thread (TEST1)

Comment: and you got something like this:
  INFO 6447 --- [pool-1-thread-1] stckovflw.example.ScheduledTask          : Started schedule at thread = pool-1-thread-1
 INFO 6447 --- [          TEST1] s.example.ConfirmReservationTask         : Run confirmReservations on TEST1
  INFO 6447 --- [         TEST11] s.example.ConfirmReservationTask         : Run confirmReservations on TEST11
 INFO 6447 --- [         TEST10] s.example.ConfirmReservationTask         : Run confirmReservations on TEST10
 INFO 6447 --- [         TEST17] s.example.ConfirmReservationTask         : Run confirmReservations on TEST17

Comment: can you share your logs with my @Scheduled example above ?